# cookie check is not working by input value

Tags: javascript, cookies

JavaScript

```javascript
var dc = document.cookie;
var nv = dc.split('; ');
var cookie = new Object();

for(i = 0; i < nv.length; i++){
    eq = nv[i].indexOf('=');
    cookie[nv[i].substring(0, eq)] = unescape(nv[i].substring(eq + 1));
}

// type 1
//this check is working 
if(cookie['name']){
    alert(document.cookie);
    alert("this is avaliable");
}else{
    alert(document.cookie);
    alert("this is not avaliable");
};

// type 2
//this check is not working error undefined; 
function checkGroup(cn_name){
    document.cookie = cn_name;
    alert(cookie[cn_name]);
};
```

I am using `cookie[]` to check is my cookie avaliable , the type 1 check is working cause I input plant text, but type 2 I trying to use value on my `cookie[]` and it did not work.

How do I make it work ?

Comment: i dont think so, it checkGroup it return my undefined, can you help me check it ?

Comment: <img id="image1" name="image_Group1" onclick="checkGroup(this.name);" src="asset/img/shirts/1-1.png">

Comment: i am using this html.

Answer (score 0):

where do you run the script? 
run it when the body is loaded, the code seems fine to me

EDIT: as i said on the comments, if u do something like `document.cookie = 'image_Group1'`, the cookie actually created is a cookie with key '' (empty) and value 'image_Group1'. Your cookie[] object has no elements with key 'image_Group1', that's why your function return undefined

Remember to always create cookies with the format key=value

for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: if u do something like `document.cookie = 'image_Group1'`, the cookie actually created is a cookie with key '' and value 'image_Group1'.

Your cookie[] object has no elements with key 'image_Group1', that's why your function return undefined

Comment: ohh ? so what i going to do ?

Comment: i don't really undestand why you are using that cookie, but remember always to create cookies with the format 'key=value', so then you can access your value with your cookie object with a simple `cookie['key']`

maybe create your cookie like that: `document.cookie = cn_name +'='+cn_name;`